# Aptana marks $a = [..] as a syntax error

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, aptana

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 and I have the following problem:

When I type:

```
$return = ['success' => (validation_errors() == null) ? true : false];
```

Aptana marks this line as a syntax error.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set your PHP version in Aptana to >=5.4. The array syntax with [] instead of `array()` is relatively new and depending on the parser it will show you a syntax error or not.

Right click on your project and go to Properties. Then click the "PHP Development" menu on the left, and select "PHP 5.4.x" (or something similar)

Comment: that was fast... Thanks !

Comment: Quick correction (unless Aptana has it wrong): short array syntax was introduced in PHP 5.4, not 5.5.

Comment: I tried and it is restoring back to 5.3

I even changed the file "PATH_TO_PROJECT/.settings/com.aptana.editor.php.prefs" with the following content:
eclipse.preferences.version=1
phpVersion=php5.4 But no use .. any lead on this how to approach

Comment: @stackup same here, I change it to 5.4 and it goes back to 5.3, did you manage to change it?